# Malloc an array inside a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I'm trying to `malloc` an array inside a struct but I keep getting segmentation errors when I run the program.

The `compares` function is just something I'm testing so it shouldn't be a part of the problem

```
typedef struct {
    char *string;
} prod_t;

int
main(int agrc, char **argv){
    int i = 0;
    prod_t *c = NULL;

    char str2[100] = "abcd";
    c->string = (char *) malloc( 5 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(c->string,str2);

    compares(c->stock,str2,i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to allocate memory for your `prod_t *c`.

Comment: Add `c = malloc(sizeof *c);`, then `c->string = malloc(5 * sizeof *(c->string));`

Comment: Typically, in a case like this, you'd run the program under debugger, then see it crash on some line, then examine the values of variables on that line. In this case you'd see that `c` is `NULL` when the program crashes as you try to access `c->string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allocate space for the struct before you can assign to the `string` member:

```
prod_t *c = malloc(sizeof(prod_t));
```

Also see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're allocating space for the string, but you're **not** allocating the struct at all. `c` remains set to `NULL` and you're trying to dereference it.

Allocate space for the struct before assigning to its members

```
prod_t *c = malloc(sizeof(prod_t));
```

And, as a sidenote for your *next-to-fix* error: this field doesn't exist

```
c->stock
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't cast result of malloc.  You only need to do that in C++.  In C, it can actually hide potential problems.

Second of all, you need to allocate (or statically declare) your structure.

Third, c->stock doesn't exist.  You probably meant c->string.

```
typedef struct {
    char *string;
} prod_t;

int
main(int agrc, char **argv) {
    int i = 0;
    prod_t *c = malloc( sizeof( prod_t ));


    char str2[100] = "abcd";
    c->string = malloc( 5 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(c->string,str2);

    compares(c->string,str2,i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: String literals automatically get a 0 terminator, you don't need to do it explicitly.

Comment: What, you expect me to pay attention or something :)  I fixed it now.